# Is there an Asset Pipeline-compatible engine that filters code based on environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I’d like to see something like this:

1. Works with Haml, Sass, CoffeeScript, JavaScript.
2. I could start any line (ignoring whitespace) with something like `@development@`.
3. In development, those lines would be output as normal (with the `@development@` prefix and one following space removed)
4. In production, those lines would not be output at all.

I am imagining my filenames would change from `foo.html.haml` to `foo.html.haml.envtoggle` or something like that, to support this feature.

Does anything like that exist? I don’t want to reinvent the wheel. If not, what are some pointers to construct it?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom processor to do this, and the place to start is [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt). Tilt is the template processor that Sprockets uses. And Sprockets is at the core of the pipeline.

The only tricky bit will be sorting out the environment handling side of things.

Had you considered just using a pipeline file for dev-only code that gets included in the layout for dev only?